# How can a react app be rendered in different non react webpages?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that does not include redux. The react app only has a small chatbox window that opens up in a modal. I want to render this react app in a few non-react websites some of which use normal js and some use jQuery. How can it be done?

My application is using webpack and babel. I am not using redux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Thats the point of Webpack and babel. It bundles your react code into javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am fairly new to react. Can you please inform how to launch the react app from the non react website?

Comment: The goal is to create your javascript bundle. Irrespective of what javascript library/framework you use, you use webpack/babel to compile it down to a browser readable javascript. The page then needs to consume that bundle. The code in that bundle gets executed as plain javascript.

Comment: How can data be sent to and fro from these two instances?

Comment: One way to do it would be to embed the data in the mother page, say like a Json, and have the react app scrape it. Not recommended though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, include the script for React, then your bundled script and it will work, for more information check the official guide:
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#step-2-add-the-script-tags

Also remember to add the HTML root element that your React app uses to mount.